# Need proper Syntax for Joining Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having a heck of a time trying to achieve what I want to do. I'm wondering if it can even be done? I have the following 4 tables:

```
Tables-user_names
field1  =user_id (PK)
field2  =user_name

Table-files
field1 =user_id (FK)
field2 =file_name
field3 =city_id (FK)
field4 =state_id (FK)

Table-city
field1 =city_id (PK)
field2 =city

Table-state
field1 =state_id (PK)
field2 =state
```

What I'd like to see in the sql query result is:
user_name, file_name, city, state

Is this possible or could I be steered in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Join Query to join tables :

`SELECT file_name,user_name,city,state FROM files f 
    LEFT JOIN user_name u ON f.user_id=u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN city c ON f.city_id=c.city_id
    LEFT JOIN state s ON f.state_id = s.state_id`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t1.user_name,
       COALESCE(t2.file_name, 'NA'),
       COALESCE(t3.city, 'NA'),
       COALESCE(t4.state, 'NA')
FROM user_names t1
LEFT JOIN files t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
LEFT JOIN city t3
    ON t2.city_id = t3.city_id
LEFT JOIN state t4
    ON t2.state_id = t4.state_id
```

I used `LEFT JOIN` here because a given user might not have an entry in the `files`, `state`, or `city` tables.  In this case, `NULL` would appear for the filename, city, or state columns, which we can "catch" using `COALESCE`.  In this case, I chose to replace it with `NA`, though you can modify as you wish.

Answer (score -1):

Just joining two tables could give you the result:

`SELECT u.user_name,f.file_name,f.city, f.state
FROM user_names as u
RIGHT JOIN files as f
ON f.user_id = u.user_id`